# md-tab-group tabs content not displaying its full height

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, angular-material2

I have the following snippet:

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>
      <em>Patients</em>
    </template>
    <div>

      <epimss-race-olp></epimss-race-olp>
    </div>
    <!--<epimss-patient token = 'patient->registrant'></epimss-patient>-->
  </md-tab>

</md-tab-group>
```

epimss-race-olp is a UI of height 200px. However, on display vertical scrollbars adjascent to each other are displayed instead of the UI. Scrolling via the scrollbars show the UI a small area at a time.

Why is the UI not displaying in its entiriety?

Answer (score 0):

I would have to see your css file but I think you are not giving the ui enough space to display

try this

```
<div style="min-height:200px;min-width:200px;">
  <epimss-race-olp></epimss-race-olp>
</div>
```

or in the respective css, for the parent element of epimss-race-olp

```
{
  min-height:200px;
  min-width:200px;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion already but all it does is to push the UI 200px below the button clicked to display its attached contents. If you scroll, the UI is fully displayed though. Reading [https://material.angular.io/components/component/tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/component/tabs) > Dynamic Height > By default, the tab group will not change its height to the height of the currently active tab. To change this, set the **dynamicHeight** input to true. The tab body will animate its height according to the height of the active tab. How do you set dynamicHeight

Comment: mmmm maybe it means overflow? try setting "overflow:auto" in the style or css